# Preserve imported font when writing plotly go plot to an image

Tags: python, image, plot, plotly, kaleido

I've been using Plotly Go for a while and haven't run into this issue before, but I need to make some plots that have a very specific font not found in plotly's font library.

I have successfully gotten the plots to use the proper font when viewed inside the editor, but when they are written to images, the font is changed back to the default.

I have attached a side-by-side image of the plot produced in the editor, and the .png file that is written, to illustrate the differing fonts.

[image]

I have sourced the font from a Github .tff file, and have also tried installing the font onto my local machine (windows 10) and pointing plotly at the .tff file.

Both methods yield plots with the correct font when viewed in the editor, but when I write them to images, the font is not preserved.

I have tried changing the engine to Orca, as well as explicitly using different versions of Kaleido, as I suspect that may be where the issue lies, but nothing has worked for me yet.

Here is some example code that uses the font I need:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

font = "https://github.com/google/fonts/blob/main/ofl/inter/Inter%5Bslnt%2Cwght%5D.ttf"
animals=['giraffes', 'orangutans', 'monkeys']
fig = go.Figure([go.Bar(x=animals, y=[20, 14, 23])])
    
fig.update_layout(font_family = font, font_color = '#4b9cb9', font_size = 20)
fig.show()
fig.write_image("barchart_example.png", scale=1)
```

Comment: I don't know if this is a workaround, but if you change to svg format, the font will be as intended.

Comment: I've tried that and no luck. Also, svg doesn't retain transparent backgrounds like png does.